# Call of Duty Advanced Warfare freezes about 2 minutes into Multiplayer gameplay

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

I am running Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare on my PC. I have updated all of my drivers, deleted and re-installed the game, and still no luck.

The first week I had the game it was running great. Then once I hit level 27, I'm coming across this reoccurring problem: I will be maybe 2 or 3 minutes into a multiplayer game, and it will freeze completely. My computer will not even let me Shift+Tab to the desktop or Ctrl+Alt+Del.

Any ideas? I can provide any additional info if necessary

Comment: Sounds like a overheating problem. Use a [windows temp monitor software](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=T3EAVev7F8jGsAfrjYG4DQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=windows+temp+monitor+software) and also check your video card temps in case. If any of those go high while playing, you might have some blocked fans or they are slowed by accumulated dust. Make sure your pc does not have a virus or malware also, reaching lvl 27 isn't the cause of a pc freeze.

Comment: I agree it's probably a heat issue. Does Single Player work fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it was an overheating issue, but after cracking my case open and cleaning out some accumulated dust, the game seems to be working fine.